# Representing QVT-Operational transformations in XML, JSON or or any other serialized format

Tags: data-modeling, eclipse-emf, ocl, qvt

I have a requirement where I need to parse the transformations defined in the QVT-Operational file.
I need some way to represent the QVT-Operational transformations in a json, xml or any other serialized format.

In model to model transformation performed using operational QVT in eclipse, I am able to generate a trace file in XML format. The trace file provides details on which element in the source model is mapped to which element in the target model but I also require the transformation logic. So is there any way to either convert the QVT-operational file to xml(or any serialized format) or get transformation details in the trace file ?

Answer (score 1):

Interactively there is no support since use of the unstable internal *.qvtox representation is not encouraged.

However programmatically you may save the compiled Resource to a *.qvtox XMI file and load it again later, provided you use a compatible OCL+QVTo release.

See also https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/1109554/1848331/#msg_1848331